# Unexpected String Constant; Expected : Operator THEN ; GOTO

Tags: vb6, lotus-domino, lotus

Can any body help me with this error? I don't have a debugger at home and someone ask me for help for this auto reply lotus script Thanks in advance masters :)

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim sess As New NotesSession
    Dim docNotify As NotesDocument
    Dim docCur As NotesDocument
    Dim sPrintText As String
    Dim sMessage As String
    Dim sSendTo As String
    On Error GoTo ErrGeneral
    On Error 4294 GoTo ErrBadAddress
    Set docCur = sess.DocumentContext
    If Not docCur Is Nothing Then
    If Not LCase$(docCur.Form(0)) = “nondelivery report” Then ‘Don’t bother For failed delivery reports
            ‘Only internet messages
        ‘    If docCur.hasitem(“SMTPOriginator”)  Or docCur.hasitem(“MIME_Version”) Or docCur.hasitem(“$MIMETrack”) Then
            If Not docCur.HasItem(“$AssistMail”) Then ‘isn’t sent by another agent
                If IsMessageUnique(docCur) Then
                    GoSub ResponseMessage
                End If
            End If
        ‘    End If
        End If
    End If
LeaveSub:
    Exit Sub

ResponseMessage:
    GoSub SetupMessage
    Set docNotify = sess.CurrentDatabase.CreateDocument
    docNotify.SaveMessageOnSend = False
    docNotify.Form = “Memo”
    If Not docCur.ReplyTo(0)=”" Then
        sSendTo = docCur.ReplyTo(0)
    Else
        sSendTo = docCur.From(0)        
    End If
    docNotify.SendTo = sSendTo
`Do Not need the following fields since this Is To be signed by the database owner.
‘if we ever change the signer To “Automail” Then these should be Set up properly
‘    docNotify.Principal= 
‘    docNotify.ReplyTo= 
    docNotify.Subject = “re: ” & docCur.subject(0)
    docNotify.Body = sMessage
    Call docNotify.Send(False)
    docCur.EFXResponded= Now
    Call docCur.Save(True,False)
    Return

SetupMessage:
    sMessage= “This Is an auto reply” &_
    “If you would Like you may contact him at john.doe@gmail.com, phone – 555-555-5555.“& Chr$(13) & Chr$(13)
    Return

ErrBadAddress:
    Resume LeaveSub

ErrGeneral:
    sPrintText=    “Error: ” + CStr(Err) + ” defn: ” + Error$ +  “.  Aborting Agent”
    Call ProblemNotify(sPrintText)    
    Resume LeaveSub
End Sub

Function IsMessageUnique(docCur As NotesDocument) As Boolean
    ‘Check To see If document Is the only one With this sender And subject. If so Return True 
    ‘Otherwise, Return false. We expect that multiple messages In a Day From the same source With the same subject are probably
    ‘automated responses.
    ‘We only look at the most recent day’s worth of documents, If this doc Is For a New Day, great, 
    ‘or If no match Is found For the current Day, also great
    Dim sess As New NotesSession
    Dim viewInbox As NotesView
    Dim docChk  As NotesDocument
    Dim docComp As NotesDocument
    Dim bAscending As Boolean
    Dim datRcvd As  NotesDateTime
    Dim datDoc As NotesDateTime
    Dim datComp As NotesDateTime
    IsMessageUnique=True
    Set viewInbox =sess.CurrentDatabase.GetView(“($Inbox)”)
    If viewInbox Is Nothing Then  ‘Returns False
        IsMessageUnique=False
        Exit Function    
    End If
    Set docChk = viewInbox.GetFirstDocument
    Set datDoc = New NotesDateTime(docChk.Created)
    Set docComp= viewInbox.GetLastDocument
    Set datComp = New NotesDateTime(doccomp.Created)
    If datDoc.TimeDifference(datComp) > 0 Then ‘First Document Is older than last document, sorted In Descending order
        bAscending = False
    Else
        bAscending = True
    End If
    Set datRcvd = New NotesDateTime(docCur.Created)  ‘get created Date From newly received document
    Call datRcvd.SetAnyTime
    If bAscending Then
        Set docChk = viewInbox.GetLastDocument
    Else
        Set docChk = viewInbox.GetFirstDocument
    End If
    While Not docChk Is Nothing
        Set datDoc = New NotesDateTime(docChk.Created)
        Call datDoc.SetAnyTime
        If Not datDoc.TimeDifference(datRcvd) = 0 Then ‘not sent On same Date – either New Day Or have reached previous Day
            IsMessageUnique=True
            Exit Function
        End If
        If docChk.From(0) = docCur.From(0) Then ‘Match, might Not be Not unique, check subject.
            If docChk.Subject(0) = docCur.Subject(0) Then ‘Match, definitely Not unique, End now.
                IsMessageUnique=False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        If viewInbox Is Nothing Then  ‘Returns False
            IsMessageUnique=False
            Exit Function    
        End If
        If bAscending Then
            Set docChk = viewInbox.GetPrevDocument(docChk)
        Else
            Set docChk = viewInbox.GetNextDocument(docChk)
        End If
    Wend
End Function
Sub ProblemNotify(sPrintText As String)
    Dim sess As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim docProblem As NotesDocument
    Dim item As NotesItem
    If sess.isonserver Then ‘send an e-mail Or Print To Log    
        Set db = sess.currentdatabase
        Set docProblem = db.CreateDocument        
        Set Item = docProblem.ReplaceItemValue(“Form”,”Memo”)
        Set Item = docProblem.ReplaceItemValue(“SendTo”,”Your Default Notification Mailbox“)
        Set Item = docProblem.ReplaceItemValue(“Principal”,sess.currentagent.name & ” Agent”)
        Set Item = docProblem.ReplaceItemValue(“Subject”,”Error: ” & db.Title & ” DB – ” & sess.currentagent.name & ” Agent”)        
        Set Item = docProblem.ReplaceItemValue(“Body”,”On ” & db.server & “!!” &db.filepath & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & sPrintText)
        Call docProblem.Send(False)
    Else
        Print sPrintText
        MessageBox sPrintText,0,”Problem With ” & sess.currentagent.name & ” Agent”
    End If
End Sub
```

waiting for your resonse. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment marks and strings are wrong:

```
'This is a comment
`Do Not need - not a comment
‘if we ever - not a comment
string1 = "ok"
string2 = “not ok”
```

The code looks like it was processed with a text beautifier, if you can't get the original you can fix it by replacing curly quotes with straight ones, either with search&replace (` -> ', ‘ -> ', “ -> ", ” -> ") or manually.

Your code:

```
...
If Not LCase$(docCur.Form(0)) = “nondelivery report” Then ‘Don’t bother For failed delivery reports
        ‘Only internet messages
    ‘    If docCur.hasitem(“SMTPOriginator”)  Or docCur.hasitem(“MIME_Version”) Or docCur.hasitem(“$MIMETrack”) Then
        If Not docCur.HasItem(“$AssistMail”) Then ‘isn’t sent by another agent
            If IsMessageUnique(docCur) Then
...
```

Corrected:

```
...
If Not LCase$(docCur.Form(0)) = "nondelivery report" Then 'Don’t bother For failed delivery reports
        'Only internet messages
    '    If docCur.hasitem(“SMTPOriginator”)  Or docCur.hasitem(“MIME_Version”) Or docCur.hasitem("$MIMETrack") Then
        If Not docCur.HasItem("$AssistMail") Then 'isn’t sent by another agent
            If IsMessageUnique(docCur) Then
...
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? can you rewrite the code ? :)